# what happens to existing tags when force pushed to a remote git repository?

Tags: git

I have a remote with a lot of tags pointing to older commits. I would like to force push a change. I understand that history will be lost when I force push. But, I am not sure what will happen to the existing tags since the commit ID will change for all commits when I force push now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that unless you force-push a *tag*, nothing will happen to the tag.

Branch names and tag names are both just a sort of pointer: they contain the raw hash ID of a commit,<sup>1</sup> so that Git can *find* that commit.  Git works, at a lower level, by hash ID: given the hash ID of a commit, such as `3e5524907b43337e82a24afbc822078daf7a868f`, Git can extract that commit.

Each commit itself has some set of hash IDs for its *parent* or *parents*, which means that we can say that this commit points to its parent(s).  If we draw each of these various items with arrows coming out of them, pointing to whatever it is that they point to, we get a diagram that looks like this in the simple case:

```
... <--F  <--G  <--H   <--branch
             ^
             |
          tag:v1.0
```

Suppose you use force-push to make the name `branch` point directly to commit `F` instead of commit `H`; then we might have to redraw this:

```
...--F   <-- branch
      \
       G--H   [lost / abandoned]
       ^
       |
    tag:v1.0
```

The tag name, `v1.0`, continues to point to commit `G`.  Commit `H` is no longer find-able by any name—the only name that used to let us find commit `H`, namely `branch`, is gone now.  This makes commit `H` eligible for *garbage collection* and at some point in the future, it will be truly removed from the repository.

(Note that if our diagram is incomplete, and some *other* name allows Git to find commit `H`, the commit will be retained.  A commit is *reachable* from some point in the graph if, starting at that point in the graph, there is some way to work backwards through the arrows—all of which point leftwards in these drawings, even if we've just drawn them as `--`—to reach the commit in question.  Any commit reachable from *any* reference—this includes branch names and tag names, along with other forms of reference not needed for this answer—is retained.  Thus, `G` will be retained via the tag, as will all of its parents, and its parents' parents, and so on.  Any commit that is *not* reachable is a candidate for garbage collection.)

---

<sup>1</sup>A tag can point to any object, while a branch name is constrained to point *only* to a commit.  For our purposes here, though, we'll assume your tags point to commits.